# How to write complex select statements in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, database, select, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Usually, for querying a database I write something like this:

`matchingUser = User.query.filter(username = current_user.username).first()`

However for the application I am currently working on I need a select statement with many conditionals that all have to be true.

So the statement will have ands, ors, and not equal to operators. How can I do this? 
Also, if possible, is there a way to write it as a series of if statements so it'll be easier to read?

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-where-clause

Comment: Does this work in flask-sqlalchemy as well? Because I could not find it on the documentation: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/